# Easiest way to create a plugin in C++

Tags: c++, windows, dll, plugins, interface

Everytime I look at plugin's tutorial, they look incredibly complex for the (conceptually) simple thing I'd like to do.

Let's say we are on Windows and I want to create a program with an interface, which I'd like to use to implement plugins as dynamic external libraries (dll).

So I have a header like this :

> Interface.h:

```
class Interface 
{
    public:
    virtual void overrideMe() = 0;
};
```

Which I use from another code (the plugin), so that I can create a DLL:

> MyPlugin.cpp

```
#include "Interface.h"

class MyPlugin: public Interface
{
    public:
    void overrideMe()
    {
        std::cout << "Hey, I am a specific MyPlugin DLL!" << std::endl;
    }
};

// DLL creation code blabla
```

So imagine I create from this code a library named **MyPlugin.dll**

Now I'd like to use the Interface in a generic program, but not by including headers and using traditionnal polymorphism, but by dynamically calling/loading/charging it from my dll :

> MyProgram.cpp:

```
#include "Interface.h"

int main()
{
    // Interface* i = new MyPlugin; // nope!
    Interface* i = chargeMe("MyPlugin.dll"); // How to do this?

    i->overrideMe();  // display: "Hey, I am a specific MyPlugin DLL!"
}
```

Now the questions are:

- What is the simplest way to do it using C++?
- Is there any fuction like `chargeMe("MyPlugin.dll")` in the real world?
- Do I necessarily need an external framework (like Qt) to do so or can the standard be enough?

Comment: Typically, you would also expose a plain C factory function, as in `Interface* CreatePlugin();` You would export it from a DLL via .def file. On the application side, use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to load the library and obtain a pointer to the factory function. Finally, you call the factory and get the interface pointer.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [boost::dll](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_dll.html).

Comment: Yes, that is called [`LoadLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows and [`dlopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) in Posix, although it is not easy to build a robust plugin system. You may consider some library to help you with that, e.g. [Poco](https://pocoproject.org) (see [shared libraries](https://pocoproject.org/slides/120-SharedLibraries.pdf)) or some other.

Comment: To your final bullet: You don't need an external framework, but the standard is not enough; you need to rely on implementation specific behaviour.  (It may even be undefined behaviour per the standard.)

Comment: There is no easy way.  Creating plugin systems is quite hard.

Comment: @Martin Bonner: I feared this answer

Comment: If you are on Windows take also a look at Microsoft Component Object Model. It handles plugin DLLs just through object interfaces.

Comment: @jszpilewski: Thanks, so as Martin said there is no real simple way to handle plugins systems... sad world